ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC : best practice for dynamically created controls from SQL
I am very new to ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC. What I've learned so far is the MVC structure always triggers a postback when changing views.
With my current application (which was built as a static page app in ASP.NET on .NET 4.8.1 with 1 SiteMaster/ChildPage [which swapped my sub pages inside it] ) I was able to load my navigation UI from SQL with pretty much 1 API request call unless the user refreshed the browser tab.
The goal of storing my navigation options in SQL (icon, text, etc) was so their text/icons could be changed in SQL without a code change.
In ASP.NET Core MVC, every view I load triggers the postback and I end up calling the SQL request to rebuild it otherwise it is lost. Is this normal practice with ASP.NET Core MVC? This seems like a major increase in API request due to the postback response. Is there any way to simulate how static pages worked in ASP.NET on .NET 4.8.1, with ASP.NET Core MVC so that the "outer wrapper/master/layout" stays static?
I've debated using a cookie for each nav icon (since at the moment I only have 6 options) but this seems excessive... I am also trying to avoid storing the nav in a Session object because I host my site in Azure (which has in the past shown poor response to keeping sessions alive correctly).

You could try using the Partial Views with AJAX which can help you to load the part of the page without a full postback.
You could try this below code:
wwwroot/js/site.js:
$(document).on('click', 'a.ajax-link', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        var newContent = $(data).find('#content').html();
        $('#content').html(newContent);
        window.history.pushState({ path: url }, '', url);
    });
});

Controllers/HomeController.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MyMvcApp.Models;
using MyMvcApp.Services;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyMvcApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly NavigationService _navService;

        public HomeController(NavigationService navService)
        {
            _navService = navService;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["NavigationItems"] = _navService.GetNavigationItems();
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult About()
        {
            ViewData["NavigationItems"] = _navService.GetNavigationItems();
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewData["NavigationItems"] = _navService.GetNavigationItems();
            return View();
        }
    }
}

Views/Home/About.cshtml:
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}

<div id="content">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <p>Welcome to the About page.</p>
</div>

Views/Shared/_Navigation.cshtml:
@model IEnumerable<MyMvcApp.Models.NavigationItem>

<nav>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <li>
                <a class="ajax-link" href="@item.Url">
                    <i class="fa @item.Icon"></i>
                    @item.Text - Rendered from Partial View
                </a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</nav>

Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - MyMvcApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navigation">
        @await Html.PartialAsync("_Navigation", ViewData["NavigationItems"] as IEnumerable<MyMvcApp.Models.NavigationItem>)
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Services/NavigationService.cs:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using MyMvcApp.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyMvcApp.Services
{
    public class NavigationService
    {
        private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
        // Simulating database with a static list
        private static readonly List<NavigationItem> _navigationItems = new List<NavigationItem>
        {
            new NavigationItem { Url = "/home", Icon = "fa-home", Text = "Home" },
            new NavigationItem { Url = "/home/about", Icon = "fa-info", Text = "About" },
            new NavigationItem { Url = "/home/contact", Icon = "fa-phone", Text = "Contact" }
        };

        public NavigationService(IMemoryCache cache)
        {
            _cache = cache;
        }

        public IEnumerable<NavigationItem> GetNavigationItems()
        {
            if (!_cache.TryGetValue("NavigationItems", out IEnumerable<NavigationItem> navItems))
            {
                navItems = _navigationItems.ToList();
                _cache.Set("NavigationItems", navItems);
            }
            return navItems;
        }

    }
}

This is just sample code you can modify based on your requirement.
Document link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-8.0


Thanks Jalpa for the detailed example. I think I understand everything up until the jquery event. I've attempted to test this example using the $.get() function but it always seems to not find the file. I get the following error:
   GET https://localhost:44328/Views/Shared/Test1.cshtml 404 (Not Found)

My example below:
//var url = "Test1.cshtml";
var url = "~/Views/Shared/Test1.cshtml";
//var url = "/Views/Shared/Test1.cshtml";
//var test1 = '@Url.Action("App", "Test1")';
$.get(url, function (data) { Fails here

I also think the other confusion I have is your _navService.GetNavigationItems. I assume that is a function to call your DB/API to extract the data which if true is causing me the same issue.

@narue1992  the error you are seeing because you are trying to call .cshtml file directly with ajax which is not correct way. you could try making AJAX calls to controller actions that return partial views which i have mentioned in my post.  and regarding the GetNavigationItems i have updated the code.

Thanks for the extra details related to GetNAvigationItems. I think I now have a working example. Something interesting I've realized is sometimes HotReload was not always working (ie triggered postback when changing partial views so stopping and restarting local debug fixed it and now simulated correctly. This held me up for awhile because I thought it was by design to postback). Another thing I've realized is partialviews inside a view (not layout) seemed to perform better as well. So for now I will try this structure and see how it goes. Thanks again for everything!
